# UPDATE using JOIN appends only first row value to another table, why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a target table which crossed over 1M rows. Each time I will be getting 50K rows which may contain multiple duplicated entries. Hence I have decided to store CSV data into a temp table, then from temp_table to target_table by comparing rows between two tables...

If duplicated entries found append data from temp_table to target_table else Insert into the table... I am using partition here, so ON DUPLICATE key update is not working here.. in temp_table I am not using any KEYS

I have two tables which look like below

```
temp_table

Name |  Type
John |  Civil
John |  Mech

target_table

Name | Type
John | Civil
```

When I run below query, I am getting an output of single row

```
 UPDATE target_table JOIN temp_table
 ON  temp_table.Name = target_table.Name
 SET target_table.Type = IF((LOCATE(temp_table.Type, target_table.Type) > 0) 
 target_table.Type,CONCAT(target_table.Type,',',temp_table.Type))


target_table

Name | Type
John | Civil
```

I am expecting output to be like below

```
target_table

Name | Type
John | Civil, Mech
```

May I know where it went wrong?

Comment: Dont do it. You are converting a normalized data to denormalized one.

Comment: Sir, Is there any better solution to compare two tables and insert/update @Madhur Bhaiya?

Comment: Why are you trying to store CSV values in your target table?  If you can explain this, maybe someone can give you a workaround.

Comment: Edited my question @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Set based updates aren't going to be of use to you. In my view a cursor is the only safe option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a group_concat and use a subquery in join

```
 UPDATE target_table 
 JOIN (
    select name, group_concat(Type) grouped
    from temp_table 
    group by name
 ) t ON t.Name = target_table.Name
 SET target_table.Type = t.grouped
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't.Name = target_table.Name
SET target_table.Type = t.grouped' at line 6

Comment: Not sure this works - If target_table starts off as john,aaa it will end up as john,civil,mech ie aaa is lost

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (but don't know for sure) and hopefully someone who does know will jump in and correct me, that an update join does not create a cartesian product in the way that a select would. As an attempted proof

```
truncate table temp_table;
insert into temp_table values
( 'John' , 'mech' ),
( 'John' , 'abc'  );
truncate table target_table;
insert into target_table values
('john', 'civil', 9 );

UPDATE target_table JOIN temp_table
ON  temp_table.Name = target_table.Name
set target_table.type = (concat(target_table.Type,',',temp_table.Type));

select * from target_table;

+------+------------+------+
| Name | Type       | LOC  |
+------+------------+------+
| john | civil,mech |    9 |
+------+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

note that abc from temp_table is ignored and mech is selected purely by chance.

if we change the order in temp_table

```
truncate table temp_table;
insert into temp_table values
( 'John' , 'abc' ),
( 'John' , 'mech'  );
truncate table target_table;
insert into target_table values
('john', 'civil', 9 );

UPDATE target_table JOIN temp_table
ON  temp_table.Name = target_table.Name
set target_table.type = (concat(target_table.Type,',',temp_table.Type));

select * from target_table;
```

we get

```
+------+-----------+------+
| Name | Type      | LOC  |
+------+-----------+------+
| john | civil,abc |    9 |
+------+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

where abc is picked purely by chance.

In my view the safest way to do this is on a row by row basis ie a cursor.